# app Gradle and installed successfully, but the app shuts down when started

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I've built a game with Buildbox 2.3.3.0, I've built the game with android studio and added the 64bits libs to support the new play store update, the game Gradle build is successful and also it's installed successfully but the game shuts down at the start, Showing a black screen then down.

I've tried cleaning app cash and data on my devices and then rebuild and install the game on my device, didn't work 
and also I've tried cleaning the project and rebuild it and install, didn't work as well

Comment: don't you have any error logs?

Comment: No there are no error logs, everything works well